# Кроссбраузерный аудиоплэй element_id.mp3 по клику на element

Tags: javascript

```
function go(){document.addEventListener('click',
function(e)
{
var id = e.path[2].id;
console.log(id);
var mp3 = document.getElementById('mp3');
mp3.src='../Desktop/mp3/' + id + '.mp3';
console.log(mp3.src);
mp3.load();
mp3.play();
},
false);}</script>
```

не работает в FF.

Сделал так

```
<script>function go(){document.addEventListener('click',
function(event)
{
var id = event.rangeParent.parentNode.parentNode.id;
var id2 = event.rangeParent.parentNode.id;
var id3 = event.rangeParent.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
console.log(id);
console.log(id2);
console.log(id3);
var mp3 = document.getElementById('mp3');
mp3.src='../Desktop/mp3/' + id + id2 + id3 + '.mp3';
console.log(mp3.src);
mp3.load();
mp3.play();
},
false);}</script>
```

но такой костыльной подход кажется ущербным.

Что делать? Как его кроссбраузерно?

Comment: Что такое `id + id2 + id3`?

Comment: Дело в том, что div вложенный, а эта штука от ложных несрабатываний: 2 из 3 всегда будут возвращать ничего, однако id элемента с собственно имеющимся id так точно схватится.

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. Приведите пример html кода что ли.

Comment: <body onclick="go();">   <div><div id="song1">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song1.mp3</div><div>   <div><div id="song2">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song2.mp3</div><div>

Comment: Ну и еще где-то там должно быть <audio id="mp3" src=""></audio> для галочки.

Comment: Собственно, дело даже не в этом, а в том, чтобы схватить path в firefox как-то иначе, но так, чтобы как везде.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте данный html код в вопрос. В комментариях его тяжело читать.

Comment: Да все равно никто не шарит, толку.

Comment: В смысле? Кто что не шарит? Вы вопрос нормальный зайдайте, понятный, полный.

Comment: Больше деталей, кроме упомянутых, у меня нет.

Comment: Больше того, по одному заголовку ясно, что требуется.

Comment: Я думаю, количество ответов на ваш вопрос очень хорошо показывает, насколько ваш вопрос понятен. Не хотите улучшать вопрос - ваше право. Ответ нужен вам, а не нам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Восстановив из комментариев полный код, я пришёл к выводу, что подразумевалось как-то так:

```html
<script>
function go(){
document.addEventListener('click',
 function(event){
  var id = event.rangeParent.parentNode.parentNode.id;
  var id2 = event.rangeParent.parentNode.id;
  var id3 = event.rangeParent.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
  console.log(id);
  console.log(id2);
  console.log(id3);
  var mp3 = document.getElementById('mp3');
  mp3.src='../Desktop/mp3/' + id + id2 + id3 + '.mp3';
  console.log(mp3.src);
  mp3.load();
  mp3.play();
 },false);
}
</script>
<body onclick="go();">
<div><div id="song1">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song1.mp3</div></div> 
<div><div id="song2">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song2.mp3</div></div>
<audio id="mp3" src=""></audio>
</body>
```

Долго разбираться. Хочу предложить вариант, который работает согласно Вашему замыслу:

```html
<div id="song1">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song1.mp3</div> 
<div id="song2">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song2.mp3</div>
<audio id="mp3"></audio>
<script>
var mp3 = document.getElementById('mp3');
var all_div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(i = 0; i < all_div.length; i ++){
 all_div[i].onclick = function(){
  mp3.src = this.id + ".mp3";
  mp3.play();
 }
}
</script>
```

Аудиофайлы должны быть в той же папке, что и HTML-файл. Или такой вариант:

```html
<div id="song1" onclick="go(this.id)">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song1.mp3</div> 
<div id="song2" onclick="go(this.id)">Нажми на меня, чтобы заиграла song2.mp3</div>
<audio id="mp3"></audio>
<script>
var mp3 = document.getElementById('mp3');
function go(myid){
 mp3.src = myid + ".mp3";
 mp3.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Сразу видно, что вы шарите. Большое спасибо. Второй вариант самый космический.